# How rapidly does $\Gamma(x)$ diverge as $x$ approaches $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function

Notoriously $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^{\pm}}\Gamma(x)=\pm\infty,$$ but can we be more precise (tightly) bounding from above $\left\lvert \Gamma(x) \right\rvert$ when $x$ is close to $0$? I could not find anything related, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to for instance [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20Gamma(x)&t=crmtb01), one has that when $x$ approaches $0$
$$
\Gamma(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \gamma + o(1)
$$
where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. That is, $\lvert \Gamma(x)\rvert$ behaves asymptotically like $\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert}$ around $0$.

You can also derive this from the Taylor expansion of the [reciprocal Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function#Taylor_series) at $0$.